# How to disable startup chime?

Tags: boot, sound, macbook, startup

When first booting up my MacBook Pro running Elementary OS, there's a rather loud startup sound effect. I have my desktop volume turned all the way down and also toggled off, however this doesn't seem to affect the startup sound.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: How are you booting into elementary OS? Live USB? Dual boot? Is OS X still on your system?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how you're booting into elementary OS. Most of the solutions I found were specific to booting into OS X, so you might have  more options if you still have OS X installed and/or are dual-booting. The startup chime should respect the latest software settings. I'd try the following:

- Mute the audio in OS X and see if the chime plays on reboot.

or

- Run `osascript -e 'set volume with output muted'` in Terminal before exiting OS X and see if the chime plays on reboot, or whether it continues to play on reboot after only booting into elementary OS.

As far as I know, there is no easy way to touch that `osascript` ([AppleScript](http://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html)) functionality in Linux, but [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/Python-2.4.3/dev/Mac/Demo/applescript.html) is a lead if you want to hack around. If none of the above works, I'd attempt some commands from [here](https://superuser.com/q/105420/57016) or [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/260693/how-to-disable-the-boot-sound-or-startup-chime-on-a-mac/), but do report back so we can find out what works!